# Gradient near a point which has a negative gradient

Tags: real-analysis

Let $g : (a, b) → \mathbb{R}$. Given the criteria for EVT is met, then applied to g on the closed interval $[x_1, x_2]$ within (a,b),  g achieves its minimum value on $[x_1, x_2]$. Suppose this happens at $x_1$.

If I know $g'(x_1)<0$, then why does there exists δ > 0 such that if $x_1 < x < x_1 + δ$ then $\frac{g(x) − g(x_1)}{x − x_1}$< 0?

Comment: What is the definition of $g’(x_1)$?

Comment: $g(t) = f(t) − vt$

Comment: Extreme Value Theorem.

Comment: I mean it happens at the $x_1$ I already have.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on Ted's comment,

$$g'(x_1) = \lim _{x \rightarrow x_1} \frac{g(x)-g(x_1)}{x-x_1}$$

is one of the equivalent definitions of the derivative from calculus. If we assume for contradiction that $$\frac{g(x)-g\left(x_{1}\right)}{x-x_{1}} \geq 0$$

then the desired result follows from the $\epsilon$ - $\delta$ definition of the limit. In particular let $\epsilon = \frac{-g'(x_1)}{2} > 0$. If $\left |x - x_1 \right | < \delta $, then
$$\left|\frac{g(x)-g\left(x_{1}\right)}{x-x_{1}} - g'(x_1)\right|< \epsilon$$
You should be able to manipulate that equation into $2\epsilon < \epsilon$, which clearly gives us the contradiction.